Angular 17, fade animation for when value changes, not working
I can't seem to get this to work.
In child component:
animations: [
        trigger('simpleFadeAnimation', [
            transition('*=>*', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate(600)
            ])
        ])
    ]


 <p [@simpleFade]>
    {{ fieldValue() ? fieldValue() : "-" }}
  </p>

In parent:
Here the input value is conditional, and depends on toggling a boolean in the parent
<app-child
  [fieldValue]="booleanVariable ?? false) ? field.value : field.valueAlt"/>

I can't get the text field in the child to fade when the value is toggled. It just keeps snapping to the new value. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?
Thanks in advance!
UPDATE
My final solution:

The trigger name has to match the html attribute that was the problem!
We also need to use a combination of opacity 0 -> 1 -> 0 for each word change, we can use transition to define an animation sequence which will do this for us!
child ts
import {
  animate,
  sequence,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrl: './child.component.css',
  animations: [
    trigger('showOrHide', [
      state(
        'true',
        style({
          opacity: 0,
        })
      ),
      state(
        'false',
        style({
          opacity: 0,
        })
      ),
      transition('true => false', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('.75s ease-in'),
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate('.75s ease-out'),
      ]),
      transition('false => true', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('.75s ease'),
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate('.75s ease'),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  fieldValue = input();
  toggle = input();
}

child html
<p [@showOrHide]="toggle()">
  {{ fieldValue() ? fieldValue() : '-' }}
</p>

Stackblitz Demo

I corrected for that name, but it still snaps. See here, modified your stackblitz a little, to show an alt value:   template:       <app-child   [fieldValue]="showChildComponent ? field.value : field.valueAlt"/>  ,
})
export class App {
name = 'Angular';
showChildComponent = false;
field = {
value: 'test',
valueAlt: 'testAlt',
};
ngOnInit() {
setInterval(() => {
this.showChildComponent = !this.showChildComponent;
}, 1500);
}
}

I figured it out! https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ailri4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

My upvote it's for the good use of signal input() and the beauty code in stackblitz :)
